# Plug-in CSS files not removed from SystemJS built bundle

Tags: css, bundling-and-minification, systemjs, jspm

When I bundle the JavaScript files with the JSPM bundle command and I remove my own source files to obtain a third party library bundle, my CSS files are not removed from the bundle.

My grunt config looks like:

```
lib: { // third-party libraries bundle
    files: {
        "src/lib.bundle.js": tsAboutSrcFiles + " - [about/**/*] - [core/**/*]"
    }
}
```

The CSS files that are part of the 'about' and 'core' directories are not removed and end up in the lib.bundle.js

config.js shows that the lib.bundle.js contains files such as:

```
"about/aboutbox.component.css!github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.22.js"
```

The question is: how do I remove these files from the 3rd party bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by trial and error, probably not the most elegant, but at least this works:

```
lib: { // third-party libraries bundle
   files: {
       "src/lib.bundle.js": tsAboutSrcFiles + " - [about/**/*] - [core/**/*] - [about/**/*!github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.22.js] - [core/**/*!github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.22.js]"
   }
}
```